# Keypress event goes to the DataGridview instead of a cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` inside of the `winform` with delete event handled from `toolstrip menu` which delete the selected row *(along with the object associated with that `row` in the `DataGridView`).*

Now when i try to edit the value of any `cell` *(to rename the object)*, and in the edit mode if i select some characters and press `delete`, it delete the row instead of deleting those selected characters.

What should i do to make the cell handle the event rather than the `Winform`.

snippets below:

```
this.deleteToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Delete;

this.deleteToolStripMenuItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.OnDelete);

private void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Are you working on winform ? and how are you handling the key press event, some relevant code is good to post

Comment: Do you have to KeyPreview on the form not set to true..?

Comment: also can you show the KeyPress Event code perhaps there is something else going wrong in that code block

Comment: @DJKRAZE i guess in that case it won't be handled by the gridview at all

Comment: I meant to type set to false sorry for my typo it's late

Comment: Sorry i realized that delete is being called from the toolstrip menu rather from the DGV.Edited the question.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Inside the keypress nothing happens except deleting that row and a call to delete the respective object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution :)
when i enter into edit mode i remove the delete key association

this.deleteToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.None;

and once i am done editing the cell in the OnAfterEdit i set it back to

this.deleteToolStripMenuItem.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Delete;

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try to check the properties of  of your `DataGridView` `SelectionMode`, must not `FullRowSelect`

Comment: But i want it to be fullrow select. How does that affect anyway?

Comment: so am correct that you have `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect`. If you notice the `RowHeader` is selected. so in time you want to delete the value of the cell and the `RowHeader` is selected, the first command will read is the `RowHeader` before the Cell Value you want to delete. i hope you get my point. anyway you can (RowHeadersVisible = false) [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridtablestyle.rowheadersvisible.aspx]

Comment: Yes 
SeletionMode = FullRowSelect and RowHeadersVisible = false;
Still the problem persists

Comment: so try to SeletionMode = RowHeaderSelect, so the row will not delete if you want to delete the value of the cell.

Comment: i understand what your point here, you're trying to delete the Cell Value but you dataGridView is `SelectionMode = FullRowSelect` :D